# Null in array of objects

Tags: reactjs, redux

So, I have a problem with REACT/REDUX, my array of objects returns a proper value but also return an undefined, and I don't know why. In redux dev tools it show's a null instead of undefined, also I have this error in console: **Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `task` is marked as required in `NewToDo`, but its value is `undefined`.**

Action file

```
import {ADD_TODO} from "./types";
import {GET_TODO} from "./types";

export const addTodo = (todo) => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: ADD_TODO,
        payload: todo,
    })
}

export const getTodo = () => dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_TODO,
    })
}
```

Reducer

```
import {ADD_TODO} from "../actions/types";
import {GET_TODO} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    toDos: [
        {task: 'Make a dinner', priority: '4'}
        ],

};

export default function(state=initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_TODO:
            return{
                ...state,
                toDos: [action.payload, ...state.toDos]
            }
        case GET_TODO:
            return {
                ...state,
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

A component that renders the tasks

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
class NewToDo extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props.task)

            return (
                <div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }


NewToDo.propTypes = {
    task: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default NewToDo;
```

A component with all toDos

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import NewToDo from './newToDo'
import {getTodo} from "../../actions/toDoActions";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
class ToDos extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getTodo();
    }

    render() {
        const {toDos} = this.props;
        console.log(toDos)
        return (
            <div>
                {toDos.map( todo => (
                    <NewToDo task={todo}/>
                ))}

            </div>
        );
    }
}


ToDos.propTypes = {
    toDos: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,


}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    toDos: state.toDo.toDos
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getTodo})(ToDos);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Warning: Failed prop type: The prop task is marked as required in
>   NewToDo, but its value is undefined.

You need to pass a prop called `task` to `NewToDo`.  It is undefined because you have required in your `PropTypes` a `prop` called `task` that is an `object` but somewhere along the way, you are not passing that prop.  You can pass the prop by connecting to the redux store using `mapStateToProps` as well.

Also, in your `initialState` for your `reducer`, shouldn't the default be `initialState.todos`?  Just seems like that might be more logical and then you can use the spread operator on the case of `ADD_TODO` just by spreading `[action.payload, ...state]`.

**Update**

I changed your toDoReducer.js to:

```
import {ADD_TODO} from "../actions/types";
import {GET_TODO} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    toDos: [
        {task: 'Make a dinner', priority: '4'}
        ],

};

export default function(state=initialState.toDos, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_TODO:
            return [action.payload, ...state]
        case GET_TODO:
            return [
                ...state,
            ]
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I changed your ToDo.js to:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import NewToDo from './newToDo'
import {getTodo} from "../../actions/toDoActions";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
class ToDos extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.getTodo();
    }

    render() {
        const {toDos} = this.props;
        console.log(toDos)
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {toDos.map( todo => (
                    <NewToDo task={todo}/>
                ))}

            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}


ToDos.propTypes = {
    toDos: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getTodo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,


}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    toDos: state.toDos
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getTodo})(ToDos);
```

Comment: But it is connected, i edited the post with my ToDos component, and the component is passing "task" to the NewToDo component.

Comment: Why are you saying `state.toDos.toDos` in `mapStateToProps` of 'ToDos` component?  Should you just be specifying `state.toDos` there?

Comment: Because state.toDo.ToDos is referencing to my combine reducers file with "export default combineReducers({
    toDo: toDoReducer
})"

Comment: Okay, but your state isn't going to be called toDo.toDos.  Also, your reducer (in `combineReducers`) should be called `toDos` because you have `state.toDos`.  You should then be accessing your state object as `state.toDos` and shouldn't need to say `state.toDos.toDos`.

Comment: Your `initialState` key should be called `toDos` and your `reducer` should also be called `toDos` in `combineReducers`.

Comment: I change the naming and i't shows the error: "toDos.map is not a function"

Comment: That means that `toDos` isn't an `Array`.  Trying changing `export default function(state=initialState, action)` to `export default function(state=initialState.toDos, action)` that way you pass the `toDos` array on `initialState`.

Comment: Still the same error ;/ i updated the whole project with your new code , and still i don't know what is wrong with this ;/ This is github with this project.
https://github.com/kacluk123/Redux-React-ToDo-List/

Comment: I'm having some trouble getting your project running on my machine but one thing I noticed is that you still have `const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    toDos: state.toDos.toDos
})`.  I really think it should just be `state.toDos`.  I'll work on getting your project running.

Comment: Yea, i change it now but i have an another error "TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"

Comment: @KacperŁukasik i got your project running.  I pasted some code edits I made.  After my code changes, I was able to see a text input and a button.  I assume that's what you were going for.  When the user adds input, I was able to check in redux dev tools that the state was in fact changing.

Comment: But in console do u have a array with {task: 'Make a dinner', priority: '4'} and undefined? I want to get rid of this [undefined](https://iv.pl/images/30885471531022805659.png). The problem is the code shows input from begining, everything i want is get rid of this undefined value in my array of objects.

Comment: @KacperŁukasik get rid of `componentDidMount` in `ToDos.js`.  That will solve the undefined problem.

Comment: Thank you! It work's now. So if I want to only display the state from my reducer in my component i don't need any extra function like "getToDo()"?

Comment: You don't need to call it initially.  You may want (in the future) a function called `getToDo` that only gets one of the todos in your list to display in some individual component.  But, at least for now, the way you were using it was unnecessary.  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to connect your reducer to the component page so that it has access to task from the redux store as props :

```
import * as todoSelector from ../reducer;
/* other code blocks */

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    task: todoSelector.getTask(state),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewToDo);
```

In the reducer have a selector function which return the task from state.

```
export function getTask(state) {
  const task = state.task;
  /* task manipulations to fit rendering needs */
  return task;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not connected your component to the redux store. You then also need to take the redux store and map your value to props. Try this

```
Class NewToDo extends Component {
...
 }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
task: state.toDos   
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewToDo)
```

this should link your array to `this.props.task`

Comment: I maped the value to props in ToDos component. And im passing the value from todos component to NewToDo as a props.